# density matrix elements from qutip's mesolve as a function of time

Tags: qutip

I am using qutip's mesolve for the open system dynamics of a system. I need to save all the density matrix elements as a function of time. mesolve gives the options of returning the expectation value of any given operator only. I am wondering if there is a way of having each element of the density matrix as a function of time without having to write an operator for each element. Please help if you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

If no expectation operator is specified, the entire density matrix at each time step will be saved. Something like `out = mesolve(H, rho0, tlist)`, i.e., not specifying the `e_ops`, will result in the states at each time point in tlist being stores in `out.states`.